# With GitLab CI how to disable repository clone for one job?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I need to speed up the job 'deploy'. It does not need the sources of the project, but only the artifacts.

#### How to disable project cloning for the only job?

Typical `.gitlab-ci.yml` (pseudo) looks like:

```
image: gcc

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - ./configure
  - mkdir build && cd $_
  - cmake ..
  - make -sj8
artifacts:
  paths:
  - "build/*.elf"

deploy:
  image: artifactory
  variables:
  - DO_NOT_CLONE: 1  ## WANT THIS OPTION
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - push_artifacts build/*.elf
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Checkout the variable `GIT_STRATEGY`:

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

From the documentation:

> *none* also re-uses the project workspace, but skips all Git operations (including GitLab Runner’s pre-clone script, if present). It is mostly useful for jobs that operate exclusively on artifacts (e.g., deploy).

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy